# How can I use HttpClient.PostAsync()

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I am new to C#, I am trying to consume remote API (**Rest API** deployed locally). Here is the code that I am using:

```
public void insertData(string id)
{
    HttpClient h = new HttpClient();
    h.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:51157");
    h.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    h.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));                
    var url = "http://localhost:57677/api/add";
    var d = new
       {
            eid = eid
       };
    var response = h.PostAsync(url.ToString(), d).Result;
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Successfully Added");

    }
}
```

Here I am getting an error at the time of building the solution itself, as

> Reference to type 'Task<>' claims it is defined in 'mscorlib', but it
> could not be found

How can I fix this?

Comment: Seems like a problem with .NET framework version. Can you please check what is the .net framework version from project properties?

Comment: It sounds like you have some kind of reference mismatch. Sometimes Microsoft moves classes around, so you might be referencing one library that thinks it's in `mscorlib` but it's really somewhere else.

Comment: .Net Version 3.5. But I added a reference to System.Net.http of version 4.5 for using httpClient

Comment: I think `Task` was defined in the TaskParallelLibrary  NuGet package for .NET Framework 3.5, but it was (presumably) moved to mscorlib in 4.0 or 4.5. You could try directly referencing TaskParallelLibrary to see if this satisfies it. Otherwise, you might need to update to .NET Framework 4.5 for your project.